# Error in (function () : unused arguments (height = 8, width = 8)

Tags: r, plot, height, width, unused-functions

I am trying to plot my mean-variance plot using the mvabund package in R. 
The line of script that doesn't work is:

`meanvar.plot(dat_mvabund, legend = TRUE)`

I never had any problems with it but now I get an error message like this:

`Error in (function () : unused arguments (height = 8, width = 8).`

I have tried some online suggestions but nothing seems to work. 
I also re-installed R and R studio. 
I tried to run the command on an older database where I am sure it worked before but it is not working now.

My dat_mvabund looks like this:

```
Zotu17  Zotu22

8322    12  
20539   29  
6105    26
```

This table was generated using the command: 
dat_mvabund <- mvabund(myData) where myData has:
Zotus in columns and Sample names in rows.

I hope someone can help!
Thank you!

Comment: please make your question reproducible by including a sample of your data (using the `dput` command and putting it into your question). Also include any other lines of code you think may be relevant

Comment: You might be calling the "meanvar.plot" function from another package - try specifying the mvabund version e.g. `mvabund::meanvar.plot(dat_mvabund, legend = TRUE))`

Comment: Thank you jpmam1, I have tried this but it didn't work

Comment: I've solved the problem! I had to restart my computer and change the code in this way: pdf("outputs/figures/meanvar_plot_AbsAbund.pdf", width = 5, height = 5)
meanvar.plot(dat_mvabund, legend=TRUE)